# Sql Query to Filter the Result Set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this Cash Table created in SQL Server In which i need to Know that what is the Type of Currency Note, and what is the No of Currecny and total Number.

```
1 = Amount Came
2 = Amount Gone
```

I am expecting the result by grouping the SQL Query. means if i have 1000 currency and Total Number of Currency Note is 11 [Considered as Came/Given is "1"] which makes it 11000 as total

Same way i have a currency note of 20 [which is 1 In and 1 Given] so it should not be in the desired output as has No matching or i dont have any Notes of 20. as i have Got one Note of 20 and given back 20

Expected Output is

```
Currency No of Currency Total
1000 -- 11 - 11000
500  -- 1 -- 500
100 -- 1 - 100
50 -- 1 - 50
```

[image]

Comment: whats your expected output?

Comment: i added in the query. i want to have the unique rows group by currency. and also check weather i have that currency note or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table currency(curr int,noc int,total int,cg int)

insert into currency 
Values(1000,10,10000,1),(1000,1,1000,1),(500,1,500,1),(100,1,100,1),(50,1,50,1),(20,1,20,1),(10,1,10,1),
(5,1,5,1),(2,1,2,1),(1,1,1,1),(20,1,20,2),(10,1,10,2),(5,1,5,2),(2,1,2,2),(1,1,1,2)


select a.curr,count(*),SUM(Total)
FROM
(
select x.curr curr,x.[no of currency],(x.curr*x.[no of currency]) as Total
From
(select a.curr,a.noc-isnull(b.noc,0) as [no of currency] from 

(select * from currency where cg=1) a

left join

(select * from currency where cg=2) b
on a.curr=b.curr
) x
) a
where a.[no of currency] <>0
group by curr
```

Comment: 1 = Currency Note came to Me and 2 =  currency Note Gone. i want to know what is the balance in me

Comment: yes i am working on that. SQL is throwing me lots of error when i execute this. but le me customize that with my tables and columns.

Comment: The Middle query is working fine. but i am not able to run the first main query . select currency,count(*),SUM(Total) ( It shows me error Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: That i have solved. But this query is exactly giving me the opposite result of what i am expecting

Comment: It is giving me result of 20,10,5,2,1

Comment: nope it is not giving me the results . But i really appreciate your help. you have given me almost way of how to write this query. will work on this and get this query work for me :)

Comment: can u give me sample data i wil try

Comment: Thanks for your help. got my results.i just input Isnull in couple of queries. and i am done. thanks

Comment: Hie, Ya thanks a lot. it worked. i added some more filtering required for this and its done :) thanks a lot.